# Match string with last part different

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/{{trans-template-id:(\d)+}}/i
```

And it matches `{{trans-template-id:7}}` perfectly.

However, I want to modify it so it will match `{{trans-template-hash:asdf1234}}` as well. How would I modify it?

I have gotten this far, but I don't know regex well enough it seems:

```
/{{trans-template-(id:(\d)+|hash:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)}}/i
```

Comment: What's the problem `/{{trans-template-(id:(\d)+|hash:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)}}/i` should work

Comment: according to [this](http://regexr.com/3dgfi) it doesn't match

Comment: Ah it's because I don't have the `g` (global) flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a common group, you can use

```
{{trans-template-(id|hash):((?<=id:)\d+|(?<=hash:)\w+)}}
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM6iP3/4)**

You can also use ***branch reset*** like

```
{{trans-template-(?|id:(\d+)|hash:(\w+))}}
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM6iP3/5)**

Comment: `trans-template-id:` must be followed by a `integer`. Won't the first one let `string` values slip through?

Comment: The link works perfectly. Don't know if you maybe want to add that as the answer

Comment: @Albert i have added another one..that will be much better because it won't have any empty capturing group

Comment: Instead of using these ugly lookbehinds, you should build your pattern using the branch reset feature `(?|...(...)...|...(...)...)` *(where capture groups from each branch have the same numbers)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that's amazing..i have a lot to read..i knew there would be something for this job..thanks