# Regex for colorcoding strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to colorize strings in python, inserting start/stop color sequences before/after all numbers, as well as substrings marked with a control character ( % ). Lets assume `[` and `]` are start/stop color sequence

Currently, I match the string using two substitute iterations:

Numbers: `text = re.sub(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?)', '[\\1]', text)`
Substrings: `text = re.sub(r'%(.*?)%', '[\\1]', text)`

Example string: "Test 1.23: Some %string 123 matched%"
Desired output: "Test **[1.23]**: Some **[string 123 matched]**"
Actual output: "Test **[1.23]**: Some **[string [123]** matched ]"

I've tried (in the number step) to detect if we are already in a colored area without luck, as well as removing all color tags within a *%control character sequence%*, also without luck.

Comment: that will happen obviously because of modification by your numbers `re.sub`..you cannot make them independent

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/mI9uE1/1) *seems* to work, but I'm not sure that it's really reliable...

Comment: @rock321987 I'm aware why it happens, just not how to fix it :)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I've considered the option, but it fails when only one of the cases is present ( \2 is not present)

Comment: I've [tested](https://repl.it/CV0j) it and it works

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thanks. I see it is working in Python3, any chance you can tell me why i get (unmatched group) in python 2?

Comment: The reason for that error may be that one group remains empty when other is foumd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There maybe other solutions but this may work. You need to install **[`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)** library for using ***branch reset*** feature.

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> x="Test 1.23: Some %string 123 match%ed"
>>> re.sub(r'(?|%(.*?)%|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))', r'[\1]', x)
'Test [1.23]: Some [string 123 match]ed'
```

Comment: I haven't heard of branch reset before, but this seems to work perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @AllanNørgaard i also haven't used it either till today one user pointed me about it **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37458757/1996394)** (today only) in comments..after seeing there I realized I can use that here